# How to handle Socket Exception when response time is high

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, socketexception

We are executing a test of Upload scenario where we are aware that the response time will be more than 5 minutes. Hence we have configured timeout in HTTP Request Defaults as well as in the Http request as 3600000  milliseconds. But still we are getting Socket Exception in Upload transaction . Could you please suggest how to handle this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[SocketException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html) doesn't necessarily means "timeout", it indicates that JMeter is not able to create or access [Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) connection, there are too many possible reasons, the most common are:

1. Network configuration of your server doesn't allow that many connections as you're trying to open, check the maximum number of open connections on your [application server](https://www.oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=Tune_apache2_for_more_concurrent_connections) and [operating system](https://www.filehold.com/help/technical/Windows-Server-Tuning-to-Prevent-TCPIP-Port-Exhaustion) level.
2. Your application server is overloaded and cannot handle such a big load. Make sure it has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM and especially Network metrics (these can be monitored using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/))
3. You might be experiencing the behaviour described in [JMeterSocketClosed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JMeterSocketClosed) article
4. Basically the same as points 1 and 2 but this time you need to check JMeter health, make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and maybe even consider going for [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I am trying with 1 user and getting socket exception: connection reset in upload transaction. But while tried manually the application works for the same upload transaction. We are getting error in jmeter only. Please suggest what i can configure to make this work.

Comment: If you're able to execute it manually (using browser) then you should be able to record the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just configure your browser to use JMeter as the proxy, copy the file(s) you're uploading to JMeter's "bin" folder and perform the upload. JMeter should generate appropriate configuration (HTTP Request Sampler, HTTP Header Manager, etc.)More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)

Comment: The script is ready. The problem is we are facing socket exception: connection reset during execution in upload transaction. We are executing with 1 user through Jmeter/blazemeter and getting error. But the same file is successfully uploaded in application when tried in browser manually. Is there any settings we are missing in jmeter or what configuration we can made in jmeter so that the socket exception will not encountered

Comment: I have tried below changes but same issue exists.
Implementation to HttpClient4
 In user.properties file 
httpclient4.retrycount=1
hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
In hc.parameters file : http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true